# SQL Server 2005 function call limit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, udf

So, I have an instance with SQL Server 9.0.3042 (9.0 SP2) and there's something really odd going on. I have this simple function

`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testBlock](@dummy int) 
returns int 
as Begin
    return @dummy
END`

If I do a select like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT [dbo].[testBlock](2015)), (SELECT [dbo].[testBlock](2015))
```

everything is ok. However, if I add another `(SELECT [dbo].[testBlock](2015))` (make it 3 calls) the query hangs forever. It happens with every DB on this instance and with any combination of 3 functions

What's even odder is that if I add a `FROM`, the query returns instantaneously.

`SELECT (SELECT [dbo].[testBlock](2015)), (SELECT [dbo].[testBlock](2015)), (SELECT [dbo].[testBlock](2015))
FROM myTable`

There's no concurrency here. I think that this might be an issue that affects only this version of SQL or any configuration, if I do the same test on an instance with SQL Server 9.0.5057 (SP4) it has no problems.

Please notice that the problem is having a `SELECT`with other `SELECT`s inside. If I call the three functions at the same time (select them and press F5) but without the "outter" `SELECT`, it's all good.

Also, with the sp_whoisactive I don't have any wait_type in the wait_info column.

**For context:**

This original query is not mine and I cannot edit it. The reason why this has selects inside a select is that there are some values that are returned by different functions that are used after in an `INSERT INTO ...`, meaning it's Something like:

`INSERT INTO Table T(val1, val2) SELECT (SELECT function1(1)), (SELECT function2(2))`

Comment: Do you really need to use `SELECT`s in your `SELECT` statement? Maybe there's a different way you can write your query..

Comment: Yes I do. The point is that this does not happen on the other instances

Comment: Did you try to create function `WITH SCHEMABINDING`? (insert instead / in front of `AS`)

Comment: Well `WITH SCHEMABINDING `works, but why? Even though it worked (and thank you in advance) it's not very practical to recompile every function with this **AND** in other functions there are tables being called and it would require to get everything that was created with schemabinding, drop it, alter table, and create functions again.
So, two questions: 
Why does this work?
Any other way?

Comment: Show us the execution plan from 2nd level to 3rd level

Comment: @Fernando68 Well, I would do it but somehow it now works. I don't know if the person responsable for the Instance made something. I'll try to understand it, I've only been told that it's a problem with the SQL version

Comment: @Daniel S. WITH SCHEMABINDING is required for SQL server to make sure that the function is deterministic by preventing you from changing things without recompiling of the function. Server checks whether the function is deterministic or not during compilation - if the function is associated with (uses) other objects (and it is not schema-bound) server always assumes it is non-deterministic, which causes it to exclude some of possible optimizations. There is no other way to do what this does.